# Could not find X11 fonts in R when plot

Tags: r, linux, plot, jupyter, x11

> the question is that when I tried to
> `plot(1,1)`
> it returns

```
Error in axis(side = side, at = at, labels = labels, ...): could not find any X11 fonts
Check that the Font Path is correct.
Traceback:
1. plot(1, 1) 
2. plot.default(1, 1) 
3. localAxis(if (is.null(y)) xy$x else x, side = 1, gap.axis = xgap.axis, ...) 
4. Axis(...)
5. Axis.default(...)
6. axis(side = side, at = at, labels = labels, ...)
```

So I checked the following information:

`sessionInfo()`

```
R version 4.0.3 (2020-10-10)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: CentOS Linux 7 (Core)

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /newdatc/home/*/bin/r_base/lib64/R/lib/libRblas.so
LAPACK: /newdatc/home/*/bin/r_base/lib64/R/lib/libRlapack.so

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] dplyr_1.0.7               patchwork_1.1.1          
[3] ggplot2_3.3.5             stxBrain.SeuratData_0.1.1
[5] SeuratData_0.2.1          SeuratObject_4.0.2       
[7] Seurat_4.0.4             

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
  [1] nlme_3.1-152          spatstat.sparse_2.0-0 matrixStats_0.60.1   
  [4] RcppAnnoy_0.0.19      RColorBrewer_1.1-2    httr_1.4.2           
  [7] repr_1.1.3            sctransform_0.3.2     tools_4.0.3          
 [10] utf8_1.2.2            R6_2.5.0              irlba_2.3.3
```

```
capabilities("X11")
X11: TRUE
```

```
names(X11Fonts())
'serif'
'sans'
'mono'
'Times'
'Helvetica'
'CyrTimes'
'CyrHelvetica'
'Arial'
'Mincho'
```

getOption('X11fonts')

NULL

names('X11fonts')

NULL

And in fact I also tried add export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
but did not work.
So any advice is appreciated!!!

Answer (score 0):

I chose to write
`library(showtext)`
`showtext_auto()`

before every script.